# ListView is not updating on Search filter functionality

Tags: android

I want to apply search filter functionality on my ListView in android.
i have create CustomBaseAdapter adapter. When i type something in input search i got the array list in `publishResults arrayList` in my logcat. butListView is not being update.

`CustomBaseAdapter` code,

```
        public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements  Filterable{
        Context context;
        List<RowItem> rowItems;

        List<String> arrayList;
        List<String> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
        LayoutInflater inflater;




        public CustomBaseAdapter( Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
            this.context = context;
            this.rowItems = items;

            //int position = 2;
            arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            mOriginalValues=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i = 0; i < rowItems.size(); i++)
           {
               RowItem rowItem = (RowItem)getItem(i);
               mOriginalValues.add(rowItem.getTitle());
            }

            Log.d(mOriginalValues.toString(),"mOriginalValues");

        }

        /*private view holder class*/
        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView txtTitle;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);

            holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return rowItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public RowItem getItem(int position) {
            return rowItems.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
        }


        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                    Log.d(results.values.toString(),"publishResults");
                    arrayList = (List<String>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                    Log.d(results.values.toString(),"publishResults arrayList");

                    notifyDataSetChanged(); // notifies the data with new filtered values
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();// Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                    List<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                       // mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                        mOriginalValues.addAll(arrayList);
                    }


                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        // set the Original result to return
                        results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                        results.values = mOriginalValues;
                    } else {
                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        Log.d(constraint.toString().toLowerCase(),"constraint");
                        Log.d(mOriginalValues.toString(),"mOriginalValues");

                        for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                            String data = mOriginalValues.get(i);
                            if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                                Log.d(data,"Filtered data");
                                FilteredArrList.add(data);
                            }
                            Log.d(FilteredArrList.toString(),"FilteredArrList");
                        }
                        // set the Filtered result to return
                        results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                        results.values = FilteredArrList;
                    }
                    return results;
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }


    }
```

`onCreate` method in my `Activity` as bellow,

```
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i],titles[i], TypeName[i] );
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);




        // Assign adapter to ListViez
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text

                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: you are getting data from RowItem to mOriginalValues. Then you filter value using arrayList and you obtain the value in publishResults. Whereas in getView() you use only RowItem to set in text view. You are not doing things with Filtered data. As far as I can see. If I'm Wrong Please Lemme Know.

Comment: what should i change in getView()?

Comment: You must use the arrayList in which youare getting Filtered data

Comment: for(String s : arrayList)
        if(rowItem.getTitle().equals(s)){

}

Comment: Check the answer i have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Constructor() of adapter make following changes,

```
        //int position = 2;
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mOriginalValues=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < rowItems.size(); i++)
        {
           RowItem rowItem = (RowItem)getItem(i);
           mOriginalValues.add(rowItem.getTitle());    
           arrayList.add(rowItem.getTitle()); 
        }

        Log.d(mOriginalValues.toString(),"mOriginalValues");
```

In getView() make following changes,

```
        if(arrayList == null || arrayList.size() == 0){
             arrayList = mOriginalValues;
        }

        for(String Title : arrayList)
          if(rowItem.getTitle().equals(Title)){
              holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
              holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
           }
        }
```

If there is still any problem check this too,

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    Context context;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;
    List<L> mOriginalValues;    // Original Values

    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = items;

        //int position = 2;
        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<>();
        if(rowItems!=null) {
            this.mOriginalValues.addAll(rowItems);
        }
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

     holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItems.get(position).getTitle());

     holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItems.get(position).getImageId());

     return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RowItem getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                Log.d(results.values.toString(),"publishResults");
                rowItems = (List<RowItem>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                Log.d(results.values.toString(),"publishResults arrayList");

                notifyDataSetChanged(); // notifies the data with new filtered values
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                List<RowItem> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<>();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    // set the Original result to return
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;

                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    Log.d(constraint.toString().toLowerCase(),"constraint");
                    Log.d(mOriginalValues.toString(),"mOriginalValues");

                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                        String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).getTitle();
                        if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                            Log.d(data,"Filtered data");
                            FilteredArrList.add(mOriginalValues.get(i));
                        }
                        Log.d(FilteredArrList.toString(),"FilteredArrList");
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                }
                return results;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have change the code as you have shown. but my list view is not being refresh. can you please tell me where i should write `notifyDataSetChanged();`?

Comment: @alka have checked the solution. If so update the code and lemme know

What happen when filter

Comment: @alka Did it Work

Comment: i was setting data from `RowItem`. i have just pass the filtered result into `RowItem`. then its worked.